# How to join two List<string> in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sharepoint-2010

I have 2 separate country attributes in the XML element z:row, returned from SharePoint web services.

```
var homeCountry = (from xml in doc.Descendants(z + "row") select xml.Attribute("ows_Country").Value).Distinct();

    var covCountry = (from xml in doc.Descendants(z + "row")
                      where xml.Attribute("ows_Coverage_x0020_Area_x0020_by_x00").Value != ""
                      select xml.Attribute("ows_Coverage_x0020_Area_x0020_by_x00").Value);
```

Now I want to merge both of the lists, in order to get the distinct country names and load the dropdow dox.

```
distinctCountriesList.Add("");
        distinctCountriesList.Sort();
        country.DataSource = distinctCountriesList.Distinct();

        country.DataBind();
```

Comment: try inner join on homeCountry and covCountry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var distinctCountriesList = homeCountry.Union(covCountry).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
country.DataSource = homeCountry
    .Union(convCountry)
    .ToList();

country.DataBind();
```

Comment: `.Distinct()` is redundant in this example.  `.Union()` guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Union` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx). In contrast, `Concat` would not filter duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Joinedlist = from hCountry in homeCountry.AsEnumerable()
                 join coCountry in covCountry.AsEnumerable()
                 on coCountry.<column Name> equals hCountry.<column Name>
```